# Access specific table cells

Tags: css

I have a table generated through a foreach (PHP) The problem is that I want to modify some specific cell on this table (in red) Knowing that I can not add a class, I must access it with a CSS style

**EDIT :**
I need add style to the first and last `<td>`, of the last `<tr>` with the `.child` class

Indeed, it is an ajax request that creates the `<tr>` with `.child` class So sometimes there are 2 `<tr>` and sometimes 10 `<tr>`

```css
.tb-child .child th, .tb-child .child td, .details-close {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
}

tbody > tr.child:last-child > td:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive table-padding tb-child">
  <table id="data-tb" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="data-tb_info">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="5007963">
        <td id="5007963"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="details">5007963</a>
        </td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td data-sort="0" class="sorting_1">
          <div>25</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="68">
          <div>42</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-16">
          <div>21</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="5012152">
        <td class="details-control details-close first-plan"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="details">5012152</a>
        </td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td data-sort="-22.23">
          <div>2333</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-22.2">
          <div>2334</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-29.63">
          <div>2111</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="child 5012152">
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="child 5012152">
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="bin">
          AZERTY1
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td data-sort="66.7">
          <div>1667</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="16.7">
          <div>1167</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="44.4">
          <div>1444</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="child 5012152">
        <td style="background: red"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="bin">
          AZERTY2
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td data-sort="-33.3">
          <div>667</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-33.3">
          <div>667</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-66.7">
          <div>333</div>
        </td>
        <td style="background: red"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="5012277">
        <td id="5012277"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="details">5012277</a>
        </td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td data-sort="-30" class="sorting_1">
          <div>7</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-30">
          <div>7</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-30">
          <div>7</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[jsiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0b3f3gk/)

I tried several things like:

```
tbody > tr.child:last-child > td:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px
}
```

But nothing works .. How to do?

Comment: Is that row always in the same position in the table?

Comment: `tbody tr.child:nth-last-child(2) td:first-child` to target the first red cell of the 2nd last row, `tbody tr.child:nth-last-child(2) td:last-child` to target the last child of the 2nd last row. Remove the **child combinator** selectors `>` as this targets direct children.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

I have used `nth-last-child(2)` to target the `td`'s in red.

My added Code:

```
tbody > tr:nth-last-child(2)>td:first-child,tbody > tr:nth-last-child(2)>td:last-child {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```css
.tb-child .child th, .tb-child .child td, .details-close {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
}

tbody > tr:nth-last-child(2)>td:first-child,tbody > tr:nth-last-child(2)>td:last-child {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive table-padding tb-child">
  <table id="data-tb" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="data-tb_info">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="5007963">
        <td id="5007963"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="details">5007963</a>
        </td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td data-sort="0" class="sorting_1">
          <div>25</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="68">
          <div>42</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-16">
          <div>21</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="5012152">
        <td class="details-control details-close first-plan"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="details">5012152</a>
        </td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td data-sort="-22.23">
          <div>2333</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-22.2">
          <div>2334</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-29.63">
          <div>2111</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="child 5012152">
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="child 5012152">
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="bin">
          AZERTY1
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td data-sort="66.7">
          <div>1667</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="16.7">
          <div>1167</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="44.4">
          <div>1444</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="child 5012152">
        <td style="background: red"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="bin">
          AZERTY2
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td data-sort="-33.3">
          <div>667</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-33.3">
          <div>667</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-66.7">
          <div>333</div>
        </td>
        <td style="background: red"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="5012277">
        <td id="5012277"></td>
        <td>
          <a rel="details">5012277</a>
        </td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td data-sort="-30" class="sorting_1">
          <div>7</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-30">
          <div>7</div>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="-30">
          <div>7</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But some of the styles are there which comes from **bootstarap css** so if you want to over-right them also you will have to use `!important` in your style.

sample -

```
tbody > tr:nth-last-child(2)>td:first-child,tbody > tr:nth-last-child(2)>td:last-child {
  border-radius: 4px !important;
}
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! But it does not really work on my site because the table is dynamic, so I can not put last-child (2) (sometimes there are 20)
Why when I put this: "tbody> tr.child: nth-last-child> td: first-child, tbody> tr.child: nth-last-child> td: last-child" it does not work?

Comment: @Rocstar You should probably update your question so that we can account for that. Will those cells always be red or where you just applying those styles for emphasis so we would know which cells you are trying to target?

Comment: @Rocstar if you want to style the dynamic number of `td` then you will have to use `jquery `or `javascript`, but still if the count of `<td>` is dynamic and you want the second from the last `tr` to be focus then my style will work. In other cases, it will not.

Comment: I need add style to the first and last <td> of the last <tr> with the .child class
Indeed, it is an ajax request that creates the <tr> with class .child
So sometimes there are 2 and sometimes 10 (I edited my post)

Comment: @Rocstar this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp the list of CSS selectors and there is no option to target a specific *child*  with the specific *class* `CSS` has not grown that much, so its better to use `jQuery`